# How to multiply strings without overflow by c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer

I tried to solve [Multiply Strings](https://leetcode.com/problems/multiply-strings/) by c++ by this approach, but I cannot avoid integer overflow by change type from `int` to `long long int` or `double`. Python won't overflow, so my code works like below.

`Given two non-negative integers num1 and num2 represented as strings, return the product of num1 and num2, also represented as a string.`

**Python** works:

```py
class Solution:
    def multiply(self, num1: str, num2: str) -> str:
        n = len(num1)  # assume n >= m
        m = len(num2)
        if n < m:
            num1, num2 = num2, num1
            n, m = m, n
        product = 0
        for i in range(1, m + 1):
            multiplier = int(num2[m - i])  # current character of num2
            sum_ = 0
            for j in range(0, n):  # multiply num1 by multiplier
                multiplicand = int(num1[n - j - 1])
                num = multiplicand * (10 ** j) * multiplier
                sum_ += num
            product += sum_ * (10 ** (i - 1))
        return str(product)
```

**C++** failed:

```cpp
string multiply(string num1, string num2) {
    int n = num1.size();
    int m = num2.size();
    if (n < m) {
        std::swap(num1, num2);
        std::swap(n, m);
    }
    long long int product = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; ++i) {
        int multiChar = num2[m - i] - '0';
        long long int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n ; ++j) {
            int charCand = num1[n - j - 1] - '0';
            long long int num = charCand * ((pow(10, j))) * multiChar;
            sum += num;
        }
        product += sum * ((pow(10, i - 1)));
    }
    
    return std::to_string(product);
}
```

As far as I have tested, some cases are OK, but overflow seems unavoidable if the number is too big. Is there any way to fix my code?

**Testcase**:

```
"12323247989"
"98549324321"
```

```
runtime error: 1.05355e+20 is outside the range of representable values of type 'long long' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:28:17
```

Expected:
`"1214447762756072040469"`

Comment: Python has arbitrary precision numbers (i.e. their range can be dynamically extended instead of overflowing). C++ doesn't work that way with its numeric types. You either have to use your own arbitrary precision types (from a library or making them yourself), or rethink the algorithm for multiplication to avoid overflow scenarios.

Comment: Please show a [mre] including what your code is supposed to go, inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs without using external links

Comment: What's the code supposed to do?

Comment: @Cookie, your has no `main`, hence it's not runnable.

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong. Hold the answer in a `string` and not `long long int`. You are using `pow(10, j)`, which again *should be replaced with string concatenation*. The question statement itself says: *You must not use any built-in BigInteger library or convert the inputs to integer directly*. Using `long long int` defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Enlico Main would be trivial anyway: `int main() { std::cout << multiply("12323247989", "98549324321") << std::endl; return 0; }`, so I'm fine with leaving that one out.

Answer (score 0):

You are not on the right way. Imagine how you would do that by hand:

```
abc*def
-------
   xxxx
  xxxx0
 xxxx00
-------
```

You just add single digits as well, don't you? Only those of same significance – possibly considering some carry.

You might rather reproduce the same in code, too. Producing overflow that way is much less likely (I assume that after multiplying single digits summing up the results in a single integer – recommending an unsigned type for – is acceptable; if not, you'd have to build up a `std::string` again). The sign you calculate independently, just as you'd do by hand as well.

One difference to multiplication by hand we'll have, though: By hand you would create rather large intermediate numbers by multiplying one number with each digit
of the other number. That would require to store these intermediate numbers as strings again, e. g. in a vector. More efficient, though, is identifying those digit pairs of which the multiplication results in the same significance.

These will be `0|0 -> 0; 0|1, 1|0 -> 1; 0|2, 1|1, 2|0 -> 2`, and so on. You produce these pairs by:

```
for(size_t i = 0, max = std::max(num1.length(), num2.length); i < max; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        if(j < num1.length() && i - j < num2.length())
        {
            // iterate backwards for easy carry handling
            size_t idx1 = num1.length() - j;
            size_t idx2 = num2.length() - (i - j);
            // multiply characters at num1[idx1] and num2[idx2] and add result to sum
        }
    }
    // add carry
    // calculate last digit and  a p p e n d  to a result string
    // update carry
}
// append '-' sign, if result is negative
std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
```

Building up the string in reverse order is more efficient, as you do not need to move the subsequent characters all the time. (Untested code, if you find a bug, please fix it yourself).

The loops are in my preferred variant; if you feel better with another, feel free to change; just be aware that with signed types you can produce endless loops if you try e. g. `for(unsigned i = n; n >= 0; --i /* overflows to UINT_MAX */)`.

Side note: You should accept the input strings by reference (`std::string const& num1, std::string const& num2`), that avoids the needless copies arising by accepting by value.

Comment: While I wouldn't use single characters, but groups of 4 (32 bit) or 9 (64 bit) from LSD: `reproduce [multiplication by hand] in code` is The Way to go! Tedious enough with up to 40k elementary products to muse about Toom-Cook.

Comment: (not upvoting because I don't *quite believe* `for (size_t j = num2.length(), last = j - num1.length() + i ; j-- > last ; )` matches how I'd by hand *add single digits […] of same significance*.)

Comment: @greybeard Using groups makes the code more complex, which is why I didn't rely on. One has to consider overflows both while multiplying and while summing up, so one has to carefully select group sizes and used integer type. Problem rises the more the longer the numbers are. Multiplication implementation was broken, indeed (not sure what I had in mind when writing...).